# How do I replace multiple words in a String variable with a random element in an array each time?

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops, arraylist

I have a string variable and I want to replace the placeholder (%) with a different element in a array each time another % occurs. How do I create a loop that randomly inserts a different word in each placeholder(%) of the string variable. Key in mind the ideal solution uses a loop.

```
//This is the code I have so far

ArrayList<String> wordsList = ...

String sentence = "A % is a series of related sentences developing a central %, called the %. Try to think about paragraphs in terms of thematic unity: a paragraph is a % or a group of % that supports one central, unified idea";

Random rand = new Random();

libStory = sentence.replace("%", wordsList.get(rand.nextInt(wordsList.size())));

    System.out.println(sentence);
```

So after the loop is complete the sentence variable would look like this...

String sentence = "A (RANDOMWORD1) is a series of related sentences developing a central (RANDOMWORD2), called the (RANDOMWORD3). Try to think about paragraphs in terms of thematic unity: a paragraph is a (RANDOMWORD4) or a group of (RANDOMWORD5) that supports one central, unified idea";

```
_______________________________________________
```

However with the replace function I get

String sentence = "A (RANDOMWORD1) is a series of related sentences developing a central (RANDOMWORD1), called the (RANDOMWORD1). Try to think about paragraphs in terms of thematic unity: a paragraph is a (RANDOMWORD1) or a group of (RANDOMWORD1) that supports one central, unified idea";

---

The loop I attempted to use is...

```
while((line = wordReader1.readLine()) != null){
  randIndex = rand.nextInt(wordsList.size());

  sentence = sentence.replace("%",wordsList.get(randIndex));

  }
```

Also I have this...

```
for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
   randIndex = rand.nextInt(wordsList.size());

   sentence = sentence.replace("%",wordsList.get(randIndex));
```

}

Comment: You already know you need a loop, yet I don't see a loop in your attempt. Why?

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: I tried using a loop but the loop uses the same random array element to replace all the placeholders with the same word

Comment: Post the code that produces that "incorrect" solution then

Comment: My issue is with the loop, (i didn't include it here b/c its useless and doesn't work properly). @BeshambherChaukhwan

Comment: Ok sure, give me a moment @f1sh

Comment: Include it and we'll tell what were you missing. It'll help you understand the do's and don'ts much better way

Comment: Just included it @BeshambherChaukhwan

Answer (score 1):

Obviously there are a number of ways this could be achieved in Java, but one simple method would be to use the variant of `String.indexOf` that lets you search from a given position. By using the previously identified position as the starting point you can identify each occurrence of `%` and replace it with a randomly chosen word.

```
List<String> wordsList = Arrays.asList("WORD1", "WORD2", "WORD3", "WORD4", "WORD5");

String sentence = "A % is a series of related sentences developing a central %, called the %. Try to think about paragraphs in terms of thematic unity: a paragraph is a % or a group of % that supports one central, unified idea";

Random rand = new Random();

StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
for(int idx=0;;)
{
    int nidx = sentence.indexOf("%", idx);      
    if(nidx < 0) 
    {
        b.append(sentence.substring(idx));
        break;
    }
    b.append(sentence.substring(idx, nidx));
    b.append(wordsList.get(rand.nextInt(wordsList.size())));
    idx = nidx+1;
}

System.out.println(b.toString());
```

Output:

```
A WORD4 is a series of related sentences developing a central WORD3, called the WORD2. Try to think about paragraphs in terms of thematic unity: a paragraph is a WORD2 or a group of WORD5 that supports one central, unified idea
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming an element can be chosen multiple times (but it still is random whether it does):

```
for(int index = sentence.indexOf("%"); index != -1; index = sentence.indexOf("%")){
    sentence = sentence.substring(0,index) +
        wordsList.get(rand.nextInt(wordsList.size())) +
        sentence.substring(index+1);
}
```

But this code starts the search for the "%" from the start of the string for every "%". Meaning, it can be optimized if you want to.

Comment: Thank you, but when I try to run the code I get an error for -sentence[index]. The error says "array required, but String found". Does this mean, I should convert each word in the string to an array element? @Kenny

Answer (score 0):

The `replace` method in class String replaces ALL the occurences of char/CharSequence with the replacement char/CharSequence.
What you need is the `replaceFirst` method and use to replace the % char/string one after the other. Maybe in combination with `indexOf` method to check if % is still present in the string.

Answer (score 0):

// your arraylist

```
ArrayList<String> wordsList = ...;
```

// shuffle it

```
import java.util.*;

Collections.shuffle(wordsList);
```

// your sentence

```
sentence = "A % is a series of related sentences developing a central %, called the %. Try to think about paragraphs in terms of thematic unity: a paragraph is a % or a group of % that supports one central, unified idea";
```

// split it with placeholder (%)

```
 s = sentence.split('%');
```

// start looping and inserting

```
sentence = "";
count = 0;
for(String i : s){
   if(count >= wordsList.size()){
      count = 0;
      Collections.shuffle(wordsList);
   }
   sentence = sentence + i + wordsList[count];
   count = count + 1;

print(sentence);
```

// It works fine even if '%' is in starting or in ending or in middle of string.

Comment: Can for (i in s) be used in java, or is it javascript? @MALNEEDIVAMSI

Comment: Oh sorry I have mentioned python 'for' loop. I updated it now for Java